# Monotouch Check collision of two Frames

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to check if two frames have a collision or check if a frame overlays another frame?

It is possible for me to calc it but I only want to know if there is another solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RectangleF` has an `InsersectsWith` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectanglef.intersectswith.aspx

Same is available in MonoTouch.